# "Out of memory" in MAGMA

Tags: group-theory, computational-algebra

I'm trying to find some information about Sporadic simple groups of the large order using MMAGM and ATLAS of Brauer. While I am sure that the memory of the cpu is enough, after while, MAGMA says that out of memory. May I do any thing to solve a problem?

Comment: In case you were not fully aware, memory here very likely means RAM, not physical memory. I have run out of RAM sometimes when doing hefty computations in Mathematica, though this was with an old and highly inefficient processor a few years ago. You should first open up your system monitor and see what is happening with your RAM in real time, then check to see if you are unnecessarily doing computations within computations (e.g. integrals inside of integrals or hefty loops within hefty loops). It could also be the case that MAGMA is only allowing itself a portion of your overall RAM.

Comment: The Monster group, for example, has order approximately $8 \times 10^{53}$.   I don't know what you were trying to do, but it's very easy to exhaust all conceivably available time and memory with something like that.  Maybe you accidentally asked MAGMA to enumerate all the elements...

Comment: It is impossible to answer this without knowing anything about the computation you are trying to do

Comment: I am trying to know about the centralizer of $3$ - elements of the schur cover of the O'Nan group O'N. But I can not even obtain the $3$-Sylow subgroup of the mentioned group.